# Identifying the position of a building footprint on a land parcel

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, land-use, footprint

I am looking to try classify where a building footprint falls on a land parcel.
I have identified the amount of free space that is available on a land parcel and am looking to try quantify this further.
When referring to the building position, I would like to identify if it is situated at the back of a land parcel or in the front of a parcel, or off to the side of the parcel (relative to the road)

Comment: You have not provided enough context for anyone to give you a meaningful answer. Show pictures of what you're trying to do.